# Integral of csc(3x)

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, arc-length

I am trying to understand the solution to an arc length question.

Integrating:
$$
=\int_{\frac{\pi}{9}}^{\frac{5 \pi}{18}} \csc (3 x) d x
$$

The workbook has:
$$
=\left.\frac{-1}{3} \ln (\csc (3 x)+\cot (3 x))\right|_{\frac{\pi}{9}} ^{\frac{5 \pi}{18}}
$$

where does the negative come $\frac{-1}{3}$ from?

I thought the integral would have been:
$$
=\left.\frac{1}{3} \ln (\csc (3 x)+\cot (3 x))\right|_{\frac{\pi}{9}} ^{\frac{5 \pi}{18}}
$$

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure the book has no printing error?

Comment: @Math-Learner There's no printing error; OP missed the minus sign in the antiderivative

Comment: If you want to avoid minus sign then $\int \csc x dx = \ln |\csc x - \cot x| + c$. Again if you multiply the numerator and denominator of the term inside $\ln$  by $\csc x + \cot x $ you will get desired result as your text book $

Comment: Thank you!  I missed the (-) in my notes for the integral for csc(x) = -ln |cscx + cotx| + C.   I had written = ln |cscx + cotx| + C.  What a stupid mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Note:

$$\int \csc(x)dx = -\log |\csc(x)+\cot(x)|+C$$

So, the minus sign is there.

Answer (score 0):

Well, to show where the solution comes from we can write:

$$\csc x=\csc x\cdot\frac{\cot x+\csc x}{\cot x+\csc x}=\frac{\csc x\cot x+\csc^2 x}{\cot x+\csc x}\tag1$$

Now, when we integrate:

$$\int\csc x\space\text{d}x=\int\frac{\csc x\cot x+\csc^2 x}{\cot x+\csc x}\space\text{d}x\tag2$$

Subsitute $\text{u}=\cot x+\csc x$, so:

$$\int\csc x\space\text{d}x=\int-\frac{1}{\text{s}}\space\text{ds}=\text{C}-\ln\left|\text{s}\right|\tag3$$